# how to use DocumentComplete Event with Gecko Webbrowser c#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, gecko, readystate

I'm creating an application that contains "geckoWebBrowser" in c #. But I have to wait the complete loading a web page, and then continue to execute other instructions.

Please help me with my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        while (listBox1.Items.Count != 1)
            {
                 geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);

                 // i want to perform below thing after web page load completes

                 listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                 listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                 int i = listBox1.Items.Count;
                 string str = Convert.ToString(i);
                 label2.Text = str;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    while (listBox1.Items.Count != 1)
        {
             geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new EventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
             geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff here      
}
```